# Why there always exists a fuchsian model $R$ satisfies the normalization condition?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $R$ be a compact boundary free riemann surface. Let $\Gamma$ be its fundamental group. Then $R\cong H/\Gamma$ where I abused notation for $\pi_1(R)\cong\Gamma$.

There is ambiguity coming from $\delta\in Aut(H),\Gamma'=\delta\Gamma\delta^{-1}$ with $H/\Gamma'$ defining same riemann surface. Let $A_i,B_i$ be generator of the fundamental group and I am going to abuse notation to denote $A_i,B_i$ the corresponding elements in $\Gamma$.

So we normalize the generator $A_i,B_i$ according the following. 
a) $B_i$ has repelling and attractive fixed points at $0,\infty$ respectively.
b) $A_i$ has its attractive fixed point at $1$.

Q: How do I know there is always such a Fuchsian model with generator normalized according to $a),b)$ for each given genus $g>1$ riemann surface $R$?

Comment: You can't do that simultaneously for all the generators, that would mean all the $B_i's$ would commute. You can do that for 2 particular elements (up to choosing inverses though, I think) due to 3-ish transitive action on the boundary by $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$. Not sure if your question is the former or the later I mention.

Comment: @PaulPlummer I am not sure whether the author of the book means the former or the later. In any case, I do not see how I can always conjugate by something to normalize my generators. This is basically the preliminary construction of Fricke embedding for Teichmuller space of genus $g$ compact surfaces. Would you mind clarify why one cannot do this simultaneously for all generators? I knew there are 2g generators subject to 1 relation.

Comment: I can explain both later today. Do you know the orientation preserving isometry group is PSL(2,R), acting Mobius transformations? I would recommend looking in Fuchsian Froups by Katok if you are unfamiliar with them (in one way or another it answers all these questions)

Comment: @PaulPlummer The orientation preserving isometry part being $PSL_2(R)$ is clear. It seems that the author thought this is obvious whereas I did not find this statement obvious at all somehow. Thanks.